Is it possible to switch between the nouveau driver and the Intel driver?
I know there is a thread similar to my question (attached link below), but I think it is outdated considering the latest versions of Ubuntu.
My laptop has the Nvidia optimus system.
Because when installing version 24.04 of Ubuntu the proprietary Nvidia drivers for my graphics card are no longer supported, and I am recommended to use nouveau, I would like to know if there is any way to switch the use of the nouveau driver and the Intel driver, such as It is done with prime-select when having the proprietary Nvidia driver installed.
If I enter the following command the output is:
lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel driver in use: nouveau

And with this command:
    gines@gines-K53SD:~$ lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [GeForce 610M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GeForce GT 610M
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau

Thanks a lot
How can I switch between Nouveau and INTEL video driver?

I'd try that DRI_PRIME=1 option with nouveau, alternatively, you may want to install 22.04 and use the proprietary driver.

I don't want to use the proprietary driver, I prefer to have the latest LTS version of Ubuntu. On the other hand, if I have to use "DRI_PRIME=1", does it mean that the system always uses the Intel driver by default? And in that case, couldn't it be indicated to use the nouveau driver by default?
Searching the internet a lot, I found this answer that I think applies to my case, but when changing vgaswitcheroo I don't know how to check if it has been changed or not, that is, if it takes effect.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/568378/nvidia-optimus-with-nouveau-drivers

The output of glxinfo -B should indicate which driver is used.

Thank you. It seems that by default the integrated graphics card is always used, and I understand that in order to use the dedicated card with the nouveau driver it will be necessary to use DRI_PRIME=1.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please don't put [SOLVED] in the question title and the answer inside the question. Click on the Answer Your Own Question button below and write a complete and detailed answer. Then after the wait time accept your answer as "correct" by clicking on the gray check mark  next to your answer and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Because the proprietary Nvidia 390 driver is no longer officially supported for kernels 6.X onwards, it is possible to consider using the free nouveau driver as an alternative.
In this case, the Nvidia Optimus system would no longer work (and all the packages that could use it), since it only works when it detects Nvidia proprietary drivers. If we use the free nouveau driver on a computer where there is an integrated Intel card, by default the drivers of the integrated Intel card will always be used, and we can check this with one of the following commands:
glxinfo -B


glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"

So, if we want to use the dedicated Nvidia card with the nouveau driver, we have no choice but to indicate before the command that opens the application that will use the Nvidia card, the prefix DRI_PRIME=1, for example:
DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears

We can also check the use of the aforementioned parameter with the following commands:
DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer" (for dedicated graphics card)


DRI_PRIME=0 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer" (for integrated graphics card)

